# Firebase credentials file on maui macos app

Tags: json, firebase, macos, maui

Good morning. I am developing a net maui app but I am experiencing the following problem: On windows it works perfectly, on mac I can not connect to the database as I can not trace the file with firebase credentials.

```
string basePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
string credentialsPath = Path.Combine(basePath, "giogo-dee69-firebase-adminsdk-fsksp-1cf7a95106.json");

Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", credentialsPath);

       try
        {
            FirestoreDb db = FirestoreDb.Create("giogo-dee69");
        DocumentReference coll = db.Collection("NomeCollezione").Document("Capoccione");

        Modello DaInserire = new Modello();

        DaInserire.Username = "Picciotto";
        DaInserire.NumeroCapelli = 19;

    await coll.SetAsync(DaInserire);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Errore di connessione a Firestore: " + ex.Message);
        }
```

The result:
TestFirebase[1325:25275] Errore di connessione a Firestore: Error reading credential file from location /Users/*************/Projects/TestFirebase/TestFirebase/bin/Debug/net7.0-maccatalyst/maccatalyst-x64/TestFirebase.app/Contents/MonoBundle/giogo-dee69-firebase-adminsdk-fsksp-1cf7a95106.json: Could not find file '/Users/**************/Projects/TestFirebase/TestFirebase/bin/Debug/net7.0-maccatalyst/maccatalyst-x64/TestFirebase.app/Contents/MonoBundle/giogo-dee69-firebase-adminsdk-fsksp-1cf7a95106.json'.

TestFirebase[1325:25275] Please check the value of the Environment Variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS.

I don't understand if it does not copy the file at the time of compilation (with Windows it does and macOS does not) or if it is wrong way to find the folder with the file. Thanks to anyone who can help me.

Comment: Meanwhile, thank you. I would like the file to be hidden and not available in the Finder. I would like it to be available only to the app that uses it. In fact, in the finder it is located but the path also depends on my username, how do I find the path from the app independently?

Comment: Do you mean the json file from Google? Is it put in the Resource/Raw folder  AND set Build Action to "MauiAsset"?

Comment: Yes. It's in Raw sub-folder and i set property "MauiAsset" and "copy if new"

Comment: Hi, have you checked the ```credentialsPath``` value? Is it right as expected?

Comment: I tried to scroll through all the folders and files that are found from "BaseDirectory" down with this function:

'code'
string appPath = NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath;
string[] directories = Directory.GetDirectories(appPath);
foreach (string directory in directories)
{
 string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(directory);
 foreach (string file in files)
  {
   Debug.WriteLine("File: " + Path.GetFileName(file));
    }
 }
'code'
I find only 2 files and not the affected one.
Thank you for your interest and help

Comment: Hi, I have not heard from you for a couple of days. Please let me know if there is anything that I can help here. @Gabriele Tedeschi

Comment: Sorry. I was convinced that I had answered. I said that what you linked to me was very useful, but I also had to be careful to queue up everything "dest. Close();" Now I'm struggling with save permissions for files downloaded from firebase, but that's another problem entirely. Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's similar to this issue: [SetEnvironmentVariable for GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS works on windows but give error on android.](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9963) and [mattleibow's comment](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9963#issuecomment-1239746065) gives a solution on cross platform which might be help.

First, set the credentials file in Raw sub-folder and set property "MauiAsset" and "copy if new".

Then read the file at runtime and store in a temp folder or any other folder:

```
//new path we will copy the file to. 
var newPath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, "giogo-dee69-firebase-adminsdk-fsksp-1cf7a95106.json");

// read the file in Resource/Raw in this way
using var json = await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync("giogo-dee69-firebase-adminsdk-fsksp-1cf7a95106.json");
//create the new path and copy the original json file here
using var dest = File.Create(newPath);
await json.CopyToAsync(dest);

Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", newPath);
```

Also, use `dest.Close();` as [MahmoudAlEssawi comment](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9963#issuecomment-1239976655).

Then you may find the credential file in new path and we could read it.

Hope it works!

Comment: Sorry. I was convinced that I had answered. I said that what you linked to me was very useful, but I also had to be careful to queue up everything "dest. Close();" Now I'm struggling with save permissions for files downloaded from firebase, but that's another problem entirely. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: @GabrieleTedeschi Glad you solve it! If above answer is helpful, please accept it as answer(click the ✔ in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue. Thanks in advance!